# Kohana 3 ORM missing NOT_WHERE?

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm

In Kohana is there anyway for me to easily negate a nested boolean set ?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE NOT ( (id = 1 OR name like 'bob') and col2 = 333 )
```

i've gotten this code...

```
$db->and_where(col2, 333)
   ->and_where_open()
        ->or_where(id, 1)
        ->or_where(name, bob)
   ->and_where_close
```

which generates

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (id = 1 OR name like 'bob') and col2 = 333
```

how do i wrap all that stuff in a **NOT** ?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this, this is not exact what you want but will give you an opinion:

```
$db->and_where(col2, 333)
   ->and_where_open()
    ->or_where('id', '!=', 1)
    ->or_where('name', '!=', 'bob')
    ->and_where_close
```

in manual I saw this sentence: "Limiting the results of queries is done using the where(), and_where() and or_where() methods. These methods take three parameters: a column, an operator, and a value."

here is the link: http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/database/query/builder

Comment: the logical contra-positive works, but i'm trying to create a query by reading in an external data structure which stores logical rules, so this sort of transform on the fly makes me uncomfortable... eh A for effort.

Comment: actually, what you have isn't the contrapositive.  you have (id != 1 OR name != 'bob') and col2 = 333 which is NOT equal to NOT((id = 1 OR name like 'bob') and col2 = 333)

Answer (score 0):

DB::Expr comes to rescue!

Your must write something like this:

```
$query = DB::select('users')
    ->where(DB::Expr("NOT ( (id = 1 OR name like 'bob') and col2 = 333 )"))
    ->execute();
```

if i remember the syntax correctly. Possibly DB::Expr must be packed in an array, it has been a long time since i worked with Kohana.

API reference:

http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Database_Expression

ORMs are good for basic operations, but for even somewhat complicated queries they can become a real PITA.